# pass variable form javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

there is a hidden field would like to use the value of this field in the graph.
it's possible? Below is an example of code that I used.

```
<input type="hidden" name="valor" id="valor" value="20" />


window.onload = function () {
var teste = (document.getElementById("valor").value);
dataPoints: [
{ label: "apple",  y: 10  },
{ label: "grape",  y: teste  }]
```

thank you

Comment: `teste` is a string. You will have to parse it as a number: `parseInt(teste, 10)`

Comment: You have not added thee closing braces to the function

Comment: so what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively get value as you suggest.

Your code do not work because you just need to close your function braces :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var teste = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  dataPoints: [
    { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
    { label: "grape",  y: teste  }
  ];
} // <= here
```